# C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/gl.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I was using QtCreator for some time to play with OpenGL, and everything was ok. But finally i needed to attach a debugger to QtCreator, so i have installed windows 7 SDK. From this time i get error:

```
C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include\QtGui\qopengl.h:122: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/gl.h': No such file or directory
```

It is a problem only on my office computer, when I work at home everything compiles. So the problem is maybe with compiler?

Comment: problem is exactly as it specified by compiler - it can't find GL/gl.h (which should come w/ some opengl sdk)

Comment: Check what include directories you are feeding in to the compiler. Are you usint QtCreator to run the compiler? In that case just add a line to the .pro file `INCLUDEPATH += <your path>` where <your path> is the path to GL/gl.h

Comment: Have you added `QT += opengl` to your .pro file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me today...

For some reason the QT installer defaults to the MSVC **2012 32Bit** OpenGL kit instead of the correct (in my case) MSVC **2013 64bBit** OpenGL kit.

So I would check if there is a mismatch between the installed kits and your OS and/or MSVC version.

In my case opening the *MaintenanceTool.exe* (in the Qt dir) selecting *Package Manager* then uninstalling the "bad" kit and selecting the "good" one solved the issue.

Edit: in the package manager it refers to Prebuilt components, but they show up in Qt Creator as kits...